# Problems with divs and <a>

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, fixed

I'm having a weird problem (never happened to me before) with a simple site I'm developing for a client.

I have 3 DIVs in fixed position, the first one set as background, the second one on top of this one and the last one is hidden (I'm going to put a sample at the bottom).

```
<body>
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Some Text</h1>
    <p>Another text...</p>
    <div class="cf">
      <a href="#popup">A button</a>
      <a href="tel:000">A call</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="popup"><p>Here some content</p></div>
</body>
```

The problem is that appears several errors, or maybe are the same all, but P and A are not selectable, when I try to click on A #popup should appear but I can't press it. When I try to select the text, everything just disappear.

The problem is like when you try to do something on your windows computer but this is slow and leaves a "shadow" behind when you move it and to erase that "shadow" you have to move again the window. You got the idea?!

Which is weird is that this problem only appears on chrome.

Any idea what happened?!

Comment: The code you've provided shouldn't produce that result. Do you have any javascript you can share with us, and/or replicate the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/73AtM/

Comment: This may just be a mistake, but the popup isn't appearing in that code, as far as I can tell, because there isn't anything with the id `popup?` I love the colours in the fiddle by the way

Comment: No. I didn't put the popup there because I erased from the site but still had the same problem so I thought is a problem related to the content.

Comment: In your case, can you click on the orange link?! Because in my case, even in jsfiddle with the code I shared, I can not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `.izq, .der` and `p`:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/73AtM/2/)**

```
.izq, .der {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Okay. I officially feel silly.

Comment: Great one! Thanks for that j08691.